# Set.prototype.has() returns false even when element is present

Tags: javascript, set

I am learning Next.js, and would like to implement filter functionality based on the checkboxes selected. I am referring to this solution >> https://codepen.io/trezy/pen/GROLXqo

So far, I have the following implementation:

Code for filter function:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    products: cspaces,
    filters: new Set(),
  })
  
  const handleFilterChange = useCallback(event => {
    setState(previousState => {
      let filters = new Set(previousState.filters)
      let products = cspaces
      let boolVal = false
      if (event.target.checked) {
        filters.add(event.target.value)
      } else {
        filters.delete(event.target.value)
      }
      console.log("filters",filters)
      if (filters.size) {
        
       
        products = products.filter(product => {
           return filters.has(
            product.attributes.propertySubType.split(" ").forEach(element => {
              if((element.match(/Shop|Office|Showroom/))!=null) 
             console.log("element ", element)
          return element
          })
          )
          
        })
        console.log("products ",products)
      
      }

     

      return {
        filters,
        products,
      }
    })
  }, [setState])
```

The checkboxes:

...

```
{data.propertytype.items.map((tag, index) => (
                      <li key={tag.value}>
                        <Form.Check
                          type="checkbox"
                         
                          id={tag.value}
                          name={tag.value}
                          label={tag.label}
                          value={tag.label}
                        
                          onChange={handleFilterChange}
                        />
                      </li>
...
```

And my component using the filtered data,

...

```
{state.products.map((filteredListItems, id) => (
                      <Col
                        key={id}
                        sm="6"
                        lg="4"
                        className="mb-5 hover-animate"
                      >
                        <CardCspace data={filteredListItems} />
                      </Col>
                    ))}
...
```

`cspaces` is holding the data fetched from API. The value of `state.products` returned by filtering function is always empty. I would like to match with the categories "Shop", "Office", or "Showroom" which are displayed in checkboxes.

Sample output in console:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My Answer:

```
const set1 = new Set([{a:1, b:2}, [3, 4], 5]);

console.log(set1.has({a:1,b:2}));
// Expected output: true

console.log(set1.has([3,4]));
// Expected output: true

console.log(set1.has(5));
// Expected output: false
```

You cannot find Object or Array value using has() method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @tzztson. How would you suggest to achieve the required functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement the filter functionality. Did it for filtering based on checkboxes selected & radio buttons selected.

Implementation is as below :

The function which maintains the currently active filters i.e checkboxes selected:
I am using array instead of set for `activeFilters`

```
...
 if (event.target.checked) {
          activeFilters = [...activeFilters, event.target.value]
        } else {
          activeFilters = [...activeFilters, event.target.value]
          activeFilters = activeFilters.filter(
            (value) => value !== event.target.value
          )
        }
...
```

The code which handles the filtering:

```
...
if (activeFilters.length) {

          products = products.filter((product) => {

            let selectedCategoryProducts = activeFilters.some((filter) => {
              return product.attributes.propertySubType.split(" ").includes(filter)
            })
            
            let selectedRadioCategory =
              product.attributes.leadType === rorb
            return selectedCategoryProducts && selectedRadioCategory
          })

          
        }
...
```

Thanks!